# Motivation and examples of parabolic manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

let $(M^{n},g)$ a Riemannian manifold, we say that $M$ is parabolic if  constant functions over M are the only subharmonic functions which are upper bound, i.e, for a function $u \in C^{2}(M)$, we have $\Delta u \geq 0$ and $u\leq u^{*}<\infty$ then $u$ is constant. 
Liouville theorem for subharmonic functions asserts that $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is a parabolic manifold.

I would like two things about this definition:

1. What is motivation for study of parabolic manifolds?

   2. If $N$ is a complete Riemannian manifold , then $\mathbb{R}^{2} \times N$ is parabolic? Why?

Comment: For (2): why do you think this is true? (It is actually false: Take $N$ equal to the hyperbolic plane.)

Comment: I saw this fact in a doctoral thesis. What would be the idea to see the validity of your statement?

Comment: Take a bounded harmonic function $h$ on the hyperbolic plane and define a function $u(z, x)=h(x)$, where $z$ is the coordinate on $R^2$ and $x$ in $H^2$. Then check that $u$ is harmonic.